# Change content of a w2ui html field

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I have a w2ui popup form with a field definition  is like this:

```
{ field: 'step', type: 'html',  html: { label: '', column: 'before', span: 0, html: "xx" } },
```

On runtime I want to change the content of that field. It is not (directly) based on a record, I would say it is an arbitrary html div. For the sake of simplicity let's say let replace the value "xx" with "coucou"

in the `onOpen` event ot the popup I'v tried the followings:

```
w2ui.DocForm.set('step', {html: {html: "coucou"}});
```

It didn't work, so I tried this:

```
w2ui.DocForm.fields[0].html.html = "coucou"
```

with and without `w2ui.DocForm.refresh();` after that

The content didn't change. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found a solution.
Once I've modified the html field like this: `w2ui.DocForm.fields[0].html.html = "coucou"`, instead of calling `refresh()`, I had to call

```
w2ui.DocForm.formHTML = w2ui.DocForm.generateHTML();
```

That was the trick.
I do not understand why it working this way, while for all the other record based fields on the other way, but at least it's working now.